# How to format the displayed scores and averages according to the problem specification?

Tags: c, printf, right-justified

```
      printf("\n");   //need help with here down and formatting it all correctly
      printf("Name");
      printf("Exam1");
      printf("Exam2");
      printf("Exam3");
      printf("Average\n");
        
        printf("%-10s", name1);
        printf("%-.2f", user1score3);
        printf("%-.2f", user1score2);
        printf("%-.2f", user1score3);
        printf("%-.1f", value1);
        printf("%%\n");
       
        printf("%-10s", name2);
        printf("%-.2f", user2score1);
        printf("%-.2f", user2score2);
        printf("%-.2f", user2score3);
        printf("%-.1f", value2);
        printf("%%\n");
     
        printf("%-10s", name3);
        printf("%-.2f", user3score3);
        printf("%-.2f", user3score2);
        printf("%-.2f", user3score3);
        printf("%-.1f", value3);
        printf("%%\n");
      
    
      return 0;
    }
```

[![This is my assignment below][1]][1]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZWIT.png
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZWIT.png

I am confused as to how I am supposed to tell the code how spaced out it should be while also having the decimal place in the correct area. any help is appreciated and thank you all for your time! I would also benefit from someone explaining right and left justification if I'm misunderstanding it fundamentally. Note, this is only the bottom half of my assignment. Let me know if more is needed.

Comment: You've not specified many field widths, but the assignment tells you what widths to use.  For the heading line, you need to use both a string format (`%s` with width and alignment information) and the value.  You could print the heading line in one operation.  You could print each student's data in one operation.  It says you have to use 3 string variables and 9 double variables — that sucks, but presumably you have not learned about structures or arrays (let alone arrays of structures) yet.  They would make the coding much easier.

Comment: You need to read the specification for [`printf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) many times.  I guess that a couple of times a day for the first week, and then once a day for the next month, and then once a week for the next year, and after that, you'll probably have covered about 80% of the foibles documented.  The information on alignment is there.  The information on field widths is there.

Comment: If you transcribe that image i'll take away my downvote.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I feel like the proverb of the 710 cap applies here. Sure he's a rank noob right now but if we add up all the stuff he did right in asking this question there's real potential in this individual. Look and see, he tried to write the code, he got something that is starting to format the output (and it appears to me that he's made multiple changes to it), and he focused the question pretty well. A little oomph and he may cross the threashhold and improve on what he's given. The only blatently wrong thing here is the image link rather than text for what it's trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`printf` format specifiers. All material drawn from "The C Programming", Second Edition, B1.2

Name: string, 10 characters, left justified

`%s` is for string, to format to 10 characters would be `%10s` or to format and truncate would be `%.10s` but we want left justified so `%-.10s`.

Exam scores, 8 width, 2 decimal places

`%f` is for floating point (double) output, so that's `%8.2f`

And another score, 7 width, 1 decimal place; same way as before with different constants

And a trailing percent

That's just `%%`